# Installing old printer drivers (Canon Pixma MX850)

Tags: macos, mount, ventura, root, sip

I would like to install drivers for MX850 on macOS Ventura.

As expected, upon running the installation package I get prompted with an “incompatibility with current OS” error, which is obvious since the driver is for 10.0.3 or something like that.

I disabled auth. root and SIP, then tried mounting.

Returns:

```
mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Permission denied

mount: / failed with 66
```

I’m still unable to run installation package successfully.

Comment: Does this need a driver at all? I have a Pixma MG7150 for which Canon doesn't provide any 64bit drivers either. It works well with just the bare macOS install on Ventura (both for printing and scanning).

Comment: that one probably has AirPrint the mine does not only USB

Comment: For printing, but not for scanning.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is for the Canon Pixma MX850, Canon's website shows drivers compatible with Mojave at latest.

https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mx_series/pixma_mx850.html

It's likely that these are 32-bit drivers, which won't work on strictly 64-bit OSes, e.g. Catalina and later.

In short, even if you can install them, they won't work. This printer is likely over 15 years old.

If the printer doesn't support standard communication protocols like Airprint, or languages like PostScript, then you're at the mercy of the manufacturer to keep the drivers up-to-date.

*(Even the drivers for Windows haven't been updated for Windows 10 or 11.)*

Comment: Yes but when using Windows 10 I can install the 64 bit drivers in Win7 compatibility mode in preferences as I did on my past PC.

Comment: The Windows 7 compatibility mode is not the same as 32bit support in a 64bit OS, @MarekBílý.,

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*This is an attempt to write a canonical answer for this issue, as per the Meta post: [Where is the list of canonical questions stored for Ask Different?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/where-is-the-list-of-canonical-questions-stored-for-ask-different) I expect it to be periodically edited with the goal of becoming a comprehensive information resource.*</sup>

---

Unfortunately, that printer is no longer supported by the manufacturer.  However, there may be some recourse; it will take a little investigation and some creativity.

#### Background

Apple has been licensing and using [CUPS](https://www.cups.org/) (Common Unix Printing System) since 2002 and then [acquired it in 2007](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2007/07/apple-purchases-rights-to-cups/).  CUPS.org is the main repository for the all the built in drivers for macOS.  When you add a printer and your system connects to the Internet to download a driver, it's pulling it through CUPS.

### Is my printer compatible?

Before you begin what could be an exhaustive search for the elusive printer driver, first determine when your printer was released.  If it was prior to 2018 when [Mojave was released](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2018/06/apple-introduces-macos-mojave/) then you may face some compatibility issues because this was the [last release of macOS to support 32bit applications](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208436).

The manufacturer may have updated their drivers to 64bit or they may have retired the product with no more official support.  There may be alternatives like compatible drivers (i.e HP LaserJet, Xerox, etc.), emulation modes (EPSON, IBM, Oki, etc.) or [printer control/description languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_description_language) (PCL, Postscript, PDF, etc.) These details can be found in the printer's technical specification sheet or in the user manual.  If it's not listed, it's a safe bet that emulation modes or printer control languages are not supported.

**Printer buying tip:** *Stay away from the "home office" or "consumer" printers.  These will undoubtedly have limited driver support once they are retired.  Look for printers with Postscript and/or PCL language support.  Even if the manufacturer stops making printers altogether, there will be a PostScript or PCL PPD that keeps your printer working.*

- #### Check the manufacturer's website.

  This should be your first stop.  The printer may be supported under an older version of macOS.  If you are trying to install a printer, especially a consumer grade in a post-Mojave world, you'll need updated drivers.
- #### [Check the OpenPrinting.org Database](https://www.openprinting.org/drivers).

  The OpenPrinting database contains a wealth of information about specific printers, along with extensive driver information, the drivers themselves, basic specifications, and an associated set of configuration tools.

  - **Seach the [Driver Listing](https://www.openprinting.org/drivers)**. This is a listing of all printer drivers supported under CUPS; both generic and manufacturer supplied drivers are included
  - **Search the [Printer Listing](http://www.openprinting.org/printer_list.cgi)**.  Here you'll be able to find specific models that are supported (fully, partially, or as "paperweight").  You can search by specific model  or for all of the models supported by a manufacturer ([Example:  Canon](https://www.openprinting.org/printers/manufacturer/Canon)).  This is a great tool if you're looking to buy a used printer and want to know if it will be supported or to create a list of printers to search for.

### What to do if there are no new drivers

There are a couple of solutions to make that printer work again:

- **Buy an older, inexpensive Mac mini to act as Print Server.**  By using [Print Sharing](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-your-printer-on-mac-mchlp2424/mac) in this manner, you can extend the life of your printer because the older (pre-Mojave) version of macOS will support the 32bit print drivers that are still available.  You'll also have the added benefit of creating networked printer that you can print to from any device.
- **Install Windows**.  Yes, Windows, but not on Bootcamp.  Similar to using an older Mac mini, any inexpensive computer (Dell, HP, etc.) are more than sufficient.  In many cases there have been Windows drivers that were available long after Mac support ended.

If a physical PC is out of the question, fire up a [VirtualBox](https://virtualbox.org) (free) VM running Windows with the printer drivers installed.  It doesn't need a lot of resources since it will be for printing only and you can configure it to used a shared folder or as a network based printer.

Comment: If you're going to buy any new hardware, it might make more sense to buy a new printer!

Comment: The idea is to *extend the life of the printer* to keep it out of a landfill somewhere. But, if you’re going to buy a new printer, buy a laser and not these ridiculous ink jets.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use the scanning capabilities of your printer, I can recommend 'Vuescan' software. This is not an ad, just a happy customer. Vuescan is in the business of working to make old scanners work in MacOS.

Your printer's scanner is supported:
https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/canon_mx850.html#technical-information

Note, this will not enable you to print, only scan.