# Brother printer MFC-J4340DW(E) driver for 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: printing, driver, macos

Can anyone help me find a driver for a Brother printer MFC-J4340DW(E)
for 10.10 Yosemite ?
Thanks

Comment: https://www.brother.co.uk/support/mfc-j4340dw/downloads only goes back as far as Mojave. you could try that & see if it works. There's wont be a specific one for an OS as old as Yosemite. Many printer drivers are built-into OS X/macOS, but not for a printer than wasn't invented by the time that OS went EoL.

Comment: @Tetsujin, nope, it stops -- versionitis. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

#### It’s unlikely you’re going to find a driver.

The earliest supported macOS, per the manufacturer, is 10.14 (Mojave) which was relased at the tail end of 2018.

The [User Manual](https://support.brother.com/g/s/id/htmldoc/mfc/cv_mfc4340dw/uke/PDF/PDF.pdf) for the printer indicates a 2020 release.  Yosemite was released in 2014, 6 years *prior* to this printer coming into existence.  Manufacturers generally don’t write for EoL (End of Life) operating systems.

- The scanner is TWAIN/WIA compliant so [VueScan](https://www.hamrick.com/) should help you get your scanning working.
- According to the [Printer Specifications](https://support.brother.com/g/b/spec.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcj4340dw_eu_as), there are no [emulation modes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/404653/119271).  You need the native driver(s) for the printer and fax functions.

For further reading see [Installing old printer drivers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/454841/119271).

#### How can you get this working?

- Upgrade your macOS.  This is the best course of action as running Yosemite is akin to running Windows 7 today.
- Load a VirtualBox VM with Linux (or Windows) on Yosemite so you can print from there.  This would also work with some spare hardware.
- When purchasing a printer, avoid MFP products and get a *business  class laser* (not Inkjet) that not only have drivers with longer support cycles, but have support for CUPS drivers and multiple printer emulation modes.  They are more expensive at purchase but end up being significantly cheaper in the long run.